# i have a problem in the buttons names

Tags: java

this is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;

public class Keyboard extends BorderLayout
{
    public Panel p1 = new Panel();
    public Button[] arr = new Button[20];
    public String[] name =
    {
        "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0",
        "+", "-", "*", "/", ".", "cos", "sin", "=", "pow"
    };

    public Keyboard()
    {
    }

    public String[] getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String[] name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Panel Keyboard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            this.arr[i] = new Button("" + this.name[i]);
        }


        this.p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6));

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            this.arr[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            this.arr[i].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            this.p1.add(this.arr[i]);
        }
        this.p1.setBackground(Color.green);
        return this.p1;
    }
}
```

the array of strings that call name are have a problem...
if i write this line at the code:
`this.arr[i]=new Button("boaz");`
every button called boaz...
but i want to see at the buttons this array :

`public String[] name = {"9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","0","+","-","*","/",".","cos","sin","=","pow"};`

but when i write this line to put the strings at the name of the button:

`this.arr[i]=new Button(""+this.name[i]);`

the panel with the buttons Disappeared

what i need to write that the buttons will have the names of the array name strings?
way the code line `this.arr[i]=new Button(""+this.name[i]);`  does not work...

Comment: i write this lines like you write to me  public Panel p1=new Panel();
 public Button[] arr=new Button[20];
 public String[] name = {"9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","0","+","-","*","/",".","cos","sin","=","pow"};
 public Keyboard()
 {
  
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
  {
   this.arr[i]=new Button();
   this.arr[i].setLabel(this.name[i]);
  }
 } but still the buttons Disappeared from the applet

Comment: Reformatted; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm not sure why you're extending BorderLayout.  Without seeing the rest of your application, I'm sort of guessing here.  However, if you're looking to display your calculator buttons in a panel, an easier way is to have a Frame containing a Panel containing your grid of buttons.  Something like this:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame{
  public MyFrame() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout() );
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6) );

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
      JButton btn = new JButton(name[i]);
      p1.add(btn);
    }

    add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  private static final String[] name = {"9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","0",
      "+","-","*","/",".","cos","sin","=","pow"};
}
```

A couple of other thoughts for you:
Your code as is has an ArrayIndex exception in the first for loop of the Keyboard() method because it checks for the length of the arr[] variable but the name[] var is accessed which has a smaller size.

Also, I would strongly urge you to not have a method with the same name as the class (and constructors).  `public Keyboard()` is your class's constructor, don't have another method `JPanel Keyboard()` also.  Call it something else, anything else.

Your code uses awt classes (Panel, Button).  Learn the swing class counterparts (JPanel, JButton, JFrame, etc...).  They were created to make the GUI building tasks a bit easier.

Finally, and I can not stress this to people enough... The [online Swing tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) are excellent if you are a beginner to building GUI's in java.  There is a lot of sample code that you can learn from.